# Avoid duplicates with self-referencing entities in Sql Server table with Entity Framework navigation property

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I've got a table in SqlServer created like below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reg](
    [Reg_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RiferimentoRRN_Reg] [int] NULL,
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Reg]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Reg_Reg] FOREIGN KEY([RiferimentoRRN_Reg])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Reg] ([Reg_Id])
```

As you can see a single record can have a related entity (or not) coming from the same table.

Thus Entity Framework will create the related Reg entity if RiferimentoRRN_Reg is not null.

How can I create a query (EF or just SQL) that selects only the records with a related entity
or the entities that haven't this relationship without having any duplicated entity?

This could be an example:

```
 Reg_Id  RiferimentoRRN_Reg
|  1   |                   |
|  2   |       1           |
|  3   |                   |
|  4   |       3           |
|  5   |                   |
```

The result of the query should be:

```
 Reg_Id  RiferimentoRRN_Reg
|  2   |       1           |
|  4   |       3           |
|  5   |                   |
```

because the records with primary key 3 and 1 are referenced via the foreign key
and so they must be avoided (5 is never referenced and must be included in the result set).

This lets me use Entity Framework navigation property to navigate to the related entity (if present) avoiding any duplicated entity.

Thanks in advance and hope that my explanation is going to be clear enough.

Comment: what would happen if `Reg_Id=3` had a `RiferimentoRRN_Reg=2`? Same result set?

Comment: Our application logic implementation doesn't permit this kind of reference so this kind of situation isn't going to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick query out of my head. But note that JamieD77's commented above won't be handled in this query.

```
SELECT D1.Reg_ID, D1.RiferimentoRRN_Reg FROM Data D1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Data D2 ON D1.Reg_ID = D2.RiferimentoRRN_Reg
WHERE D2.RiferimentoRRN_Reg IS NULL
```

**UPDATE**

The below query should handle JamieDD77's comment

```
SELECT D1.Reg_ID, D1.RiferimentoRRN_Reg FROM Data D1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Data D2 ON D1.Reg_ID = D2.RiferimentoRRN_Reg
WHERE (D2.RiferimentoRRN_Reg IS NOT NULL AND D1.RiferimentoRRN_Reg IS NOT NULL) 
OR (D2.RiferimentoRRN_Reg IS NULL)
```

I'm sure you will be able to convert this into a LINQ query with ease.

Comment: This nailed it perfectly. Thank you